# Visual Studio 2019 - debugging CustomAction throws exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception, wix, windows-installer

I have a Windows Installer Project in my Visual Studio 2019 solution, using Wix Toolset 3.11.2.
Wix toolset is installed via Nuget package into solution.

I have a Custom-Action which is called by the installer. Running the installer works without any issues and the custom-action was performed as expected.

But now, I want to debug the custom-action. So, I added the following line into my custom action

```
    [CustomAction]
    public static ActionResult WriteServiceConfigFile(Session session)
    {
        Debugger.Launch();
        //More code
    }
```

Now, when i build my installer (in Debug configuration) and run it, I get asked to "Choose just In-Time Debugger" and to select my available Visual Studio instance. This works without any issues, the Debugger is launched and breaks in Line "Debugger.Launch()".
Now, when I step over or into next statement (completely independent of what next statement is), my debugger crashes and the installer is interrupted. In Visual Studio, I see many of the following exceptions:

> Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.InstallerException' in Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll

And error message in msi log file:

```
    MSI (s) (88:48) [09:18:46:363]: Executing op: ActionStart(Name=WriteServiceConfigFile,,)
Action 09:18:46: WriteServiceConfigFile. 
MSI (s) (88:48) [09:18:46:364]: Executing op: CustomActionSchedule(Action=WriteServiceConfigFile,ActionType=3073,Source=BinaryData,Target=WriteServiceConfigFile,CustomActionData=INSTALLATION_TYPE=Server;FEATURES=FeatureServer,CommonFile;HOST_URI=;PRODUCTVERSION=2.99.999;ONLY_LOCAL_REQUESTS=;IS_UPDATE=false)
MSI (s) (88:C4) [09:18:46:392]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Windows\Installer\MSI1137.tmp, Entrypoint: WriteServiceConfigFile
MSI (s) (88:40) [09:18:46:392]: Generating random cookie.
MSI (s) (88:40) [09:18:46:405]: Created Custom Action Server with PID 14180 (0x3764).
MSI (s) (88:14) [09:18:46:429]: Running as a service.
MSI (s) (88:14) [09:18:46:431]: Hello, I'm your 32bit Elevated Non-remapped custom action server.
SFXCA: Extracting custom action to temporary directory: C:\Windows\Installer\MSI1137.tmp-\
SFXCA: Binding to CLR version v4.0.30319
Calling custom action Setup.CustomActions!Setup.CustomActions.CustomActions.WriteServiceConfigFile
Exception thrown by custom action:
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object parameters, Object arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.CustomActionProxy.InvokeCustomAction(Int32 sessionHandle, String entryPoint, IntPtr remotingDelegatePtr)
CustomAction WriteServiceConfigFile returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
Action ended 09:19:00: InstallFinalize. Return value 3.
```

**But to clarify! This exception only occures if I attach the debugger. Without debugger, all works as expected**

System Details:

- Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019 Version 16.11.20
- Wix toolset 3.11.2
- Windows 10 21H2

Comment: Hello, you try first Go to Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General
Turn off "Break all processes when one process breaks". If it doesn't work, it's probably not a problem with Debug settings. I noticed you didn't share your full error message. Please share more wrong information, it will be more helpful to solve the problem.

Comment: Hmm this option didn't solve the issue :( I added the error message from the misexec logfile to the original thread

Comment: Need to modify the registry, cmd command, enter regedit to open the registry and find the following path:
KEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\FipsAlgorithmPolicy
Modify the Enable value under this path to 0

Comment: If the above operations do not work, please consider that you have a problem with custom operations. Instead of using custom actions, you should use the native Windows Installer ServiceInstall and ServiceConfigure tables, which are exposed by InstallShield under Advanced Component Settings. Create a component, add the service EXE to the component as a key file, and define the service meta.

Comment: The Enable property was already set to 0 at my system. I do not use InstallShield.

Comment: The exception you are seeing is caused by a memory access violation. This can happen if your custom action is accessing memory that it shouldn't, or if it's trying to modify memory that's read-only. When you attach the debugger, it's possible that it's interfering with the memory layout of the process and causing the exception. Could you please enable unmanaged debugging?

Comment: If I enable Unmanaged debugging, VisualStudio asks me to load the SfxCA.pdb file (which I have found in the debug zip at the wixtoolset webpage) but still no more information why the application crashes

Comment: Hello, please try again using this sentence. System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();

Comment: Debugger.Launch() is the same, I have imported the System.Diagnistics namespace

Comment: I went to check some information. Initial speculation that to fix this, you could try running your custom action in the same process as the installer. You can use the "Attach to Process" feature in Visual Studio for this. You can start the installer and then attach a debugger to the process running the installer.

Comment: Same issue when attaching the debugger

Comment: Hello, if this does not work and you confirm that your operation steps are ok, please consider that it is a Wix version compatibility problem. You need to report to the official to solve this problem.